# Jetpack Compose Webview with IFrame - link behavior

Tags: iframe, webview, android-jetpack-compose

I am migrating a project from Java/XML to Kotlin/Compose and am struggling to recreate previous behavior with a webview/iFrame.

The webview contains an iframe with a FatMap as it's source. The iframe content has some _blank links (that on a desktop open a new window) and others that interact with the map (e.g. bring up additional content).
[image]

With the Java/XML implementation, clicking the "_blank" links opened up the link in the system browser, clicking the interactive links correctly interacted with the map. This was exactly the desired behavior, and there wasn't anything special being done with intercepting links to make it work - it just did!

Original Java Code:

```
        WebSettings webSettings = binding.wvFATMAP.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mResortsVM.getFatmap().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), map->{
            StringBuilder wvData = new StringBuilder();
            wvData.append("  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \\\"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\\\">\n" +
                    "    <html>\n" +
                    "      <head>\n" +
                    "      <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1250\">\n" +
                    "      <meta name=\"FATMAP\" content=\"FATMAP\">  \n" +
                    "      <title></title>\n" +
                    "      </head>\n" +
                    "      <body id=\"body\">  \n" +
                    "<iframe src=\" " + map + "\" frameborder=\"\" allowfullscreen width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"></iframe>" +
                    "      </body>\n" +
                    "    </html>");
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(binding.wvFATMAP,true);

            binding.wvFATMAP.loadData(wvData.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");;
        });
```

On first attempt at rewrite (using the Accompanist library), the webview seemed to be handling all clicks - clicking either the _blank links or the interactive links resulted in a blank view in my webview - like it had tried to open a new page without any content.

I then implemented a custom webview client, overriding shouldOverrideUrlLoading and returning true. The interactive links now work correctly, but the _blank links do nothing, and shouldOverrideUrlLoading isn't called when they're clicked.

Here's the code I've got so far (webViewBody is same as above):

```
 val webViewState = rememberWebViewStateWithHTMLData(data = webViewBody)
    val webViewNavigator = rememberWebViewNavigator()
     val webClient = remember {
            object : AccompanistWebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                    Log.d("Accompanist WebView", "Page started loading for $url")
                }

                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                    view: WebView?,
                    request: WebResourceRequest?
                ): Boolean {
                    //   view?.loadUrl(url)
                    return true // super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
                }
            }
        }

  Column(modifier) {
 WebView(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            state = webViewState,
            navigator = webViewNavigator,
            onCreated = {
                CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(it, true)
                it.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            },
              client = webClient,
        )
    }
```

Example FatMap url: `https://fatmap.com/activity/freeride/@46.0768888,7.2824969,24320.4784125,-35.9049826,92.6848191,2388.9221056,normal`

Any ideas on how I can replicate the functionality we had with Java/XML, where the _blank links open in the system browser?